# Microsoft Sync Framework. sdf file not syncing with server

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-mobile, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

In my WM program, I use SQLCE. The .sdf file is syncronized with SQL server in my pc using SyncOrchestrator. Then, I copy the .sdf file to PDA and update certain tables by the WM application. Then, I copy back the updated .sdf file to PC and sync with the SQL server.
The thing is, the updated data are not syncing with server. I need a solution please.

Comment: have you checked what version of SQL Compact you have installed in your WM device? i would suggest enabling Sync Framework tracing in verbose mode so you can see if its actually able to detect the changes or not at all...if its detecting the changes, the trace should show if its failing to apply the changes to the sql server.

Comment: hi,WM SQL Version is 3.5. When i do any update in .sdf file when it is in PC, the sync is ok.but when i do any update when it is in PDA,the update is committed ,but sync doesnt occur. there are tracking columns for each table in .sdf which are automatically created by SyncOrchestrator. these columns are not tracking the changes.

Answer (score 0):

this has been answered here already: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/syncdevdiscussions/thread/39dd402a-a483-45f1-85ca-9b16fe541d19

the fix is to have SQL CE 3.5 SP2 on the device. SP2 introduced a new change tracking API and this is what is used by Sync Framework 2.1 as well.

the older 3.5 CE on the device is not logging the changes in the tracking metadata so no changes is detected by Sync Framework.