# Sync Mobile Database to Backend Database

Tags: mobile, windows-mobile, synchronization

I have created Application for Windows Mobile application 6 and used mobile sql database.Now I want to sync the data in mobile db to backend database(MS SQL).So please tell me how to sync the data in mobile db to backend using Microsoft Synchronization Framework

Answer (score 0):

Do any of these help with what you are trying to do?

- [Any Good Examples of Mobile Sync Framework Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1941122/153923)
- [Microsoft Sync Framework. sdf file not syncing with server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9821533/153923)
- [Synchronise sql server data between mobile device and laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10745105/153923)
- [Compressed CAB files cannot be installed by WCELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17816214/153923)